# Linux Kernel Memory Leak with Mediatek mt76x0u USB WiFi Chipset Related to skbuff_head_cache

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, out-of-memory

I am running Linux 6.1 on a 32-bit ARM Microchip SAMA5D27 processor. The board has 256 MB of RAM. I am attaching a USB dongle to the board with the Mediatek mt76x0u chipset.

On bootup I use SystemD to start wpa_supplicant 2.10 with the configuration file below. The intent is to use this platform in Ad-Hoc mode, hence the `mode=1`.

The problem I see is that eventually the kernel with panic with OOM. The board panics reliably after ~1 hour of runtime. It panics even if I stop all services except `wpa_supplicant`.
I analyzed kernel memory with `slabtop` have created the following chart to show userspace memory usage versus the largest kernel user.

[image: Memory Leak]

I believe there is a memory leak in the driver, or the driver does not work well with my low performance device due to some default kernel parameters.

I have made sure to install the very latest vendor firmware for this chipset from the linux-firmware repository.
The largest user is `skbuff_head_cache`.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate this issue?

What can I tune in the kernel related to `skbuff_head_cache`?

Versions:

```
wpa_supplicant version
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant v2.10
Copyright (c) 2003-2022, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

uname -r
6.1.22-linux4microchip-2023.04
```

Dmesg:

```
[   29.553651] mt76x0u 1-1:1.0: ASIC revision: 76100002 MAC revision: 76502000
[   32.369384] mt76x0u 1-1:1.0: EEPROM ver:02 fae:04
[   33.046717] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt76x0u
[   52.068860] mt76x0u 1-1:1.0 mediatek: renamed from wlan0
[   63.000388] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt76x2u
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

sit0      no wireless extensions.

mediatek  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TestAdHoc"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Cell: DE:AD:BE:EF:DE:AD  
          Tx-Power=20 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

WPA Supplicant configuration:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
autoscan=periodic:120
ap_scan=2
filter_ssids=1
bss_max_count=10
network={
    bgscan="simple:120:-70:3600"
    ssid="TestAdHoc"
    bssid=DE:AD:BE:EF:DE:AD
    mode=1
    #frequency=5180
    frequency=2462
    proto=WPA2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    psk="password"
    priority=100
}
```